# Executar query de select + update SQL

Tags: sql

Tenho o seguinte SQL:

```
SELECT prospect.uni_id, prospect.usu_id, prospect.pro_nome, prospect_agendamento.* FROM prospect_agendamento JOIN prospect ON(prospect.pro_id=prospect_agendamento.age_id_prospect) WHERE prospect_agendamento.age_cod_consultora_agendado = '4'
```

Nisto, eu trago os resultados em que eu preciso.
Eu preciso executar o seguinte UPDATE dentro dessa query:

```
UPDATE prospect_agendamento SET age_cod_consultora_agendado=prospect.usu_id
```

De que forma eu consigo executar uma query dentro da outra?

> Eu preciso setar o usu_id que está na tabela de prospect, para o
>   age_cod_consultora_agendado na tabela prospect_agendamento, deixarem
>   iguais

Comment: Depende o que você precisa fazer de uma SQL para outra, o que faltou dizer na pergunta?

Comment: Eu preciso setar o usu_id que está na tabela de prospect, para o age_cod_consultora_agendado na tabela prospect_agendamento, deixarem iguais

Comment: Qual é o gerenciador de banco de dados?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você pode fazer assim:

```
UPDATE prospect_agendamento
SET age_cod_consultora_agendado = P.usu_id
FROM prospect_agendamento PA WITH(NOLOCK)
INNER JOIN propect P WITH(NOLOCK) ON PA.age_id_prospect = P.pro_id
WHERE PA.age_cod_consultora_agendado = '4'
```